# R Replace variable from dataframe if another variable is TRUE

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `statistics` and a logic variable `fromWidget`, and for the variable from `fromWidget` who have 'TRUE' I want to replace `statistics$app_space` with 'Widget'. `fromWidget` and `statistics` are part of another dataframe `BPFjfiles`.

`fromWidget [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`

`statistics$app_space [1] "www" "www" "www" "www" "www" "www" "www" "www" "www" "www"`

I tried looping trough `BPFjfiles`, but this didn't work.

```
Orderplatforms <- lapply(BPFjfiles, function(x) {
  x$statistics$app_space["TRUE" %in% x$fromWidget] <- "Widget"
  x
  Orderplatforms <- x$statistics$app_space
})
```

Comment: Please make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by adding sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `"TRUE" %in% x$fromWidget` will always be true if at least one element from `x$fromWidget`is true.

To replace `x$app_space` with `"Widget"` only when `x$fromWidget` is True you can do :

```
x$statistics$app_space[x$fromWidget] <- "Widget"
```

Comment: I also got the following error _Error in `*tmp*`$statistics : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors_ . Statistics is a dataframe so I don't understand this. Thanks  for your help

Comment: Can you please post an example of `x` so I can test it on my PC ?

Comment: `x` is used in `function(x)` so it is the same structure of `BPFjfiles`

Comment: Ok, so can you give an example of `BPFjfiles`?

Comment: `BPjfiles` is a dataframe which exists out of a dataframe `statistics` and a logical variable `fromWidget`

`fromWidget [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`

`statistics$app_space [1] "www" "www" "www" "www" "www" "www" "www" "www" "www" "www`

`statistics$client_id[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`

Comment: Ok, so I think the problem is that in your function, `fromWidget` is not in `x`, can you try `x$statistics$app_space[fromWidget] <- "Widget"` ?

Comment: `Error in x$statistics$app_space[fromWidget] <- "Widget" : 
  object 'fromWidget' not found`

Comment: Can you post the result of `str(BPFjfiles)` ?

Comment: It's quite long, where would be the best place to post it?

Comment: You can add at the end of your question